# E-mail message of failed lock not identifying affected Lotus Notes documents

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I have a user who was sent several messages to his Outlook account with the following subject:

*Changes made to the database xxxx have NOT been incorporated into the database. There was a conflict detected. Your changes may be found in body of this message. A document link to the original document is attached to the end of the message.*

Unfortunately, besides the link, the body of the email is blank and the link URL is of this form: *Notes:///482567CC001B4104*. The link seems to be making reference to the database replica ID and clicking on the link opens up the database and not directly to the affected document.

I'm finding that the message is not very useful in terms of identifying the affected document. Can anyone advise me on the ways to identify the affected documents or configure the system so that it would identify/link the affected documents?

Comment: What kind of database does it link to?  It would help to know what kind of database generated that message.

Comment: It is just a Lotus Notes database. I thought the tags and the information provided in the question would answer that - unless you mean something else with your comment.

Comment: Eugh. Lotus Notes.  GLWT.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Notes Document URL is getting truncated, are your Outlook users using IMAP or DAMO to access is Lotus Notes? DAMO is preferred if possible.

**Background information**

A well formed Notes URL should like this: Notes://DOMP14/8025771200393FEC/A4D87D90E1B19842852564FF006DED4E/0EE78B1C87ED3AAE8025794F00364483

Which can be broken down like this - Notes://SERVER_NAME/DATABASE REPLICA ID/VIEW/DOCUMENTID

**How to see conflicted documents**

Based on the error message it sounds like there's some kind of replication conflict issue. That is the document is being edited at the same time by two different clients. The easiest way to see conflicts is to create a view (you can use "Copy From" to base the design off an existing view) with the following properties:

1. A column displaying `@Created`
2. Append the following code to the end of the existing View Selection Formula: `& @IsAvailable($Conflict)`
3. Bring up View Property info box, select the 2 tab (Information) and uncheck "**Show responses in hierachy**"

This will show you the documents that lost in conflict resolution - you'll find this is the often the document whose changes you wish to keep.

If you wish to promote this document to winner status you need to do the following:

1. Go to your newly created "Conflicted documents" view
2. Edit the conflict document and change the title/subject to make it easier to identify. This is because as soon as you save it, you'll see it in the view usually below the "winner" document.
3. Switch to the original view
4. Delete the original "winner" document
5. Update the title/subject of the newly promoted document.

Things can get complicated if the form is very complicated and the changes are subtle. In this case there are tools that can do the equivalent of a diff between documents, but these are usually pay for. One tool I can highly recommend YTria's [ScanEZ](http://www.ytria.com/WebSite.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_scanEZen?OpenDocument&Lang=en).